# Get class name in convenience init Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, initializer

I'm trying to implement my own version of `convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext)`, the new convenience initialiser on NSManagedObject in iOS 10. Reason being I need to make it compatible with iOS 9.

I've come up with this:

```
convenience init(managedObjectContext moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let name = "\(self)".components(separatedBy: ".").first ?? ""

    guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: name, in: moc) else {
        fatalError("Unable to create entity description with \(name)")
    }

    self.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: moc)
}
```

but it doesn't work because of this error...

> 'self' used before self.init call

Does anyone know how to get around this error, or achieve the same result in another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the type of `self` with `type(of: self)` and that
works even before `self` is initialized. 
`String(describing: <type>)` returns the unqualified type name as a 
string (i.e. the type name without the module name), and that is 
exactly what you need here:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(managedObjectContext moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))

        guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: name, in: moc) else {
            fatalError("Unable to create entity description with \(name)")
        }

        self.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: moc)
    }
}
```

You can also add an `if #available` check to use the new `init(context:)` initializer on iOS 10/macOS 10.12 or later, and the compatibility code
as a fallback on older OS versions:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(managedObjectContext moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, macOS 10.12, *) {
            self.init(context: moc)
        } else {
            let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
            guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: name, in: moc) else {
                fatalError("Unable to create entity description with \(name)")
            }
            self.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: moc)
        }
    }
}
```